# Order a postgreSQL query on a rolling period (2)

Tags: sql, postgresql

this is my query :

```
SELECT 
    type.name_type as type_name,
    extract(day from event.creation_date) as days,
    count(0) as number
FROM event, type, event_type
WHERE event.id = event_type.event_id
    AND type.type_id = event_type.type_id
AND event.creation_date between now() - interval '1 YEAR' and now()
GROUP BY days, type_name
order by min(event.creation_date) asc;
```

my issue is that when i visualize its result, there are several rows having the same day number. i would like days' numbers to act like a key so that each day number has a unique row.

the other requirement is that the result has to be ordered according to the rolling month (based on the current date), so here for example the first row is the 7 and the last row the 6.

and ideas ?

any help is appreciated :) have a nice day !

(PS : i can't provide sample data)

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you expected `count(0)` to be faster than `count(*)` then you are mistaken

Comment: 1.  It seems odd that you are pulling a full year of events, and then mingling July 7 counts with June 7 counts and May 7, etc.  Did you really mean to do that?    2.  Your tables seem to describe a many-to-many relationship between Events and Types.  This means that one event can have multiple types.  If you only want one of them, you're going to have to figure out how to choose among the many.

Comment: `FROM event, type, event_type` <<-- Please rewrite to JOIN syntax.

Comment: Pre-aggregate in a subquery, and sum in the main query.

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: thank you all for your feedback (i'll keep all of your comments in mind), but i'm not trying to optimize my code at the moment, i'd just like it to work.
@ChrisMaurer yes i mean to do that (i'm doing some statistics) ; and for the types i'm well aware of that, it is complet normal
@wildplasser i'm not sure that joining with a ```JOIN ON```would help to solve my problem... and i didn't get your second comment

and idea on how to make it work ?

Comment: @wildplasser unfortunately i'm can't provide and data...

Comment: So, we should create fake data for you? I don't think so!

Comment: You can't get one row per day number while type_name is in your Group By.  Take it out.

Comment: @wildplasser i just asked my question in case someone would know... i just can't provide and type of data...
anyway thank you for your answers

Comment: @ChrisMaurer i see what you mean you're right, but my explanation was incorrect. i would like the couple (days,type_name) to be unique... i visualize the result of my query in metabase and it allows me to stack different type_name on the same day. my real struggle is to have it ordered as i wish....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm responding to Armand's comment that '*my real struggle is to have it ordered as i wish*'

The problem is really, "How can I order a sequence of numbers as 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 31, 30, 29, etc.?"

The answer is to use modular arithmetic.  If you add `30 minus day(current_date)` to each of these numbers you get 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 54, 53, 52, etc.

If you then take the remainder (modulus) of these numbers divided by 31, you get 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21.  and voilà, you have a sequence to put in an Order By (descending).

So the answer is `Order By mod(days + 30 - day(Current_date),31) desc`